# How to animate to a bloc text field?

Tags: flutter

I want make a transition between these two pages:

[image]

When the users clicks on the `TextField` that says *Anything you want to share?*, he will have a transition to a page that looks like this:

[image]

I created the two widgets that creates the two views, and I implemented a logic that goes from the first view to the second view, but it doesn't transition and it's not as I want to be. What I want is, when the user clickso the *Anything to share?*, he will be transititioned to the view and he will have the keyboared opened directly so that he can start writing.